# How to transform Pandas DF to show count of tokens in the original DF?

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I am trying to convert a Pandas DF containing sentences into one which shows the number of words in those sentences across all columns and rows.

I have tried apply, transform, lambda functions and nested for loops.

## Works beautifully for one column

```
dat.direction.str.split().str.len()
```

## Failed Approach 1

```
def token_count(x):
    if type(x) == str:
        return x.split().str.len()
    else:
        return 0

dat.apply(token_count)
dat.transform(token_count)
```

## Failed Approach 2

```
dat.apply(lambda x:x.str.split().str.len())
dat.apply(lambda x:x.split().str.len())
dat.transform(lambda x:x.str.split().str.len())
dat.transform(lambda x:x.split().str.len())
```

## Failed Approach 3 (Before the nested for loops)

```
dat.iloc[1,3].split(" ").str.len()
```

## Output for one column

[image: 1 col op]

## Error for Approach 1 (Shouldn't be 0)

[image: Approach 1 error]
....................

## Error for Approach 3

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'
```

## Expected Output

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["this is a sentence", "this is another sentence"],
    "col2": ["one more", "this is the last sentence"],
})

pd.concat([df[col].str.split().str.len() for col in df.columns], axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### `stack`

- `stack` to one dimension
- Do your thing
- `unstack` back

---

```
df.stack().str.split().str.len().unstack()

   col1  col2
0     4     2
1     4     5
```

---

#### Using `count` instead

```
df.stack().str.count('\s+').unstack() + 1
```

---

#### `applymap`

```
df.applymap(lambda s: len(s.split()))
```

---

#### `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.str.split().str.len())
```

---

#### Setup

[Thanks to Ian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56604719/2336654)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": ["this is a sentence", "this is another sentence"],
    "col2": ["one more", "this is the last sentence"],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over each column in your data frame using your first approach.

```
out = pd.DataFrame(index=dat.index)
for col in dat:
    out[col] = dat[col].str.split().str.len()
```

Comment: Interesting. I tried that and here's the output:

`AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas`

I tried to address this in approach 1.

Comment: That means you have values in `dat` that are not being parsed as strings.